# i have a case, how to sum all commentId in this variable? Has anyone had the same case?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, javascript-objects

I have a data array, I want to sum the whole `commentId` with JavaScript.

```
const comments = [
  {
    commentId: 1,
    commentContent: 'Hai',
    replies: [
      {
        commentId: 11,
        commentContent: 'Hai juga',
        replies: [
          {
          commentId: 111,
          commentContent: 'Haai juga hai jugaa'
          },
          {
          commentId: 112,
          commentContent: 'Haai juga hai jugaa'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
      commentId: 12,
      commentContent: 'Hai juga',
      replies: [
          {
          commentId: 121,
          commentContent: 'Haai juga hai jugaa'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
    {
    commentId: 2,
    commentContent: 'Halooo'
    }
  ]
```

For example : Suppose there is commentId `[1, 2, 11, 12, 111, 112, 121]`. Hence, `commentId.length` is `7`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I've edited it

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this through recursive function. As there can be n level of nesting between comment and replies. Have a look at the following code.

```
function caluclateLength(commentsOrReplies, sum=0) {
  sum += commentsOrReplies.length
  return commentsOrReplies.reduce((total, commentorReply) => (total + caluclateLength(commentorReply.replies || [])), sum)
}
console.log(comments) // should return desired result
```